# Как получить доступ к атрибутам экземпляра класса из другого класса?

Tags: java

```
public class Ke {
    int numberOfpens;
    int numberOfpencils;

    Ke employee1 = new Ke();

    public void number() {
        employee1.numberOfpens = 3;
        employee1.numberOfpencils = 12;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class B {

    int price;
    B pen = new B();
    B pencil = new B();

    public int getPrice() {
        pen.price = 10;
        pencil.price = 5;

        // хочу сделать что-то типа этого
        return pen.price * employee1.numberOfpens + pencil.price * employee1.numberOfpencils;

    }
}
```

Comment: А откуда классу `B` знать, кто такой `employee1`?

Comment: Так вот вопрос в том, как дать знать классу B об этом?

Comment: Создать объект класса, а потом уже обращаться к нему

Comment: @LEQADA так ведь объект employee1 уже создан в другом классе и содержит значения переменных. Если я ещё раз создам такой же объект в классе B, то значения 3 и 12 будут видны для этого класса?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь применить инкапсуляцию?

Comment: @LEQADA не знаю, я пытаюсь считывать разные numberOfpens и numberOfpencils для нескольких объектов класса Ke. Т.е. потом будет employee1, employee2, employee3 ...

Comment: Я вас понял. Сейчас напишу развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Инкапсуляция

Давайте представим, что это такое. Мне очень нравится пример из книги Mala Gupta, поэтому его и приведу.

В качестве примера хорошо инкапсулированного класса из реальной жизни можно привести Банк. Банк не даёт пользоваться своими хранилищами и счетами напрямую, как и хорошо инкапсулированный класс, который не позволяет пользоваться своими переменными напрямую. Пользоваться банковскими хранилищами или счетами можно только через методы, предоставляемые банком. Хорошо инкапсулированный класс должен предоставлять методы, с помощью которых можно выполнять различные операции с переменными этого класса. Точно так же, как и банк.

## Пример

Давайте приведём самый простой пример класса Банк.

```
class Bank {
    String fullName;
    int accountNumber;
    int money;
    void takeMoney (int amount) {

    }

    void putMoney (int amount) {

    }
}
```

Ни один из переменных класса не является приватным. Любой другой класс может записать в них всё, что захочет.

```
class Customer {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Bank bankAccount = new bankAccount();
        bankAccount.money = -1000;
    }
}
```

Как видно из этого примера, класс `Bank` плохо инкапсулирован - мы смогли получить доступ к переменной из вне класса. Давайте применим инкапсуляцию к классу `Bank`.

```
class Bank {
    private int money;
    public void takeMoney (int amount) {
        if(money > 0 && money < 1000)
            money -= amount;
    }

    public void putMoney (int amount) {
        if(money > 0)
            money += amount;
    }
}
```

Применив модификатор доступа (Access modifier) `private` к переменной `money` мы обеспечили невозможность записывания в него напрямую из другого класса. И теперь запись может производиться только через наши методы. В этих методах мы можем проверять входные параметры, как нам угодно.

## Ответ на вопрос

А теперь попробуем то же самое применить относительно ваших классов.

Ke class:

```
public class Ke {
    private int numberOfpens;
    private int numberOfpencils;

    public void setNumber(int pens, int pencils) {
        numberOfpens = pens;
        numberOfpencils = pencils;
    }

    public int getPens() {
        return numberOfpens;
    }

    public int getPensils() {
        return numberOfpencils;
    }

}
```

B class:

```
public class B {
    private int price;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int priceNew) {
        price = priceNew;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        B pen = new B();
        B pencil = new B();
        Ke employee1 = new Ke();

        employee1.setNumber(3,12);
        pen.setPrice(10);
        pencil.setPrice(5);

        System.out.println(pen.getPrice() * employee1.getPens() + pencil.getPrice() * employee1.getPensils());
    }
}
```

Если будут вопросы, то задавайте, пожалуйста, в комментарии к ответу.

Comment: Большое спасибо, у вас получилось донести много полезных вещей, всё понял.